# RCTLog.h file not found error in Xcode, after adding import files in React Native app for Fabric crashlytics logs

Tags: xcode, react-native, error-handling, crashlytics, google-fabric

I installed Fabric with crashlytics in my React native app. Sometimes it is s a big problem to catch the error even if you have this setup in your app, because crashlytics don't show you the whole information about the error when your app is crashed. Therefore i decided to set logs from JS thread to Fabric, according this article https://medium.com/delivery-com-engineering/add-crashlytics-to-your-react-native-ios-app-69a983a9062a. And i has got this error **'RCTLog.h' file not found** after adding this lines of code to my AppDelegate.m:

```
#import <asl.h>
#import "RCTLog.h"
```

I'm not so strong in SWIFT. Can you tell me please where can i find this files or maybe give me an example how can i create it please.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the decision. I have created RCTLog.h file, it is a header file, in the same directory like AppDelegate.m.
RCTLog.h:

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import <React/RCTAssert.h>
#import <React/RCTDefines.h>
#import <React/RCTUtils.h>

#ifndef RCTLOG_ENABLED
#define RCTLOG_ENABLED 1
#endif

/**
 * Thresholds for logs to display a redbox. You can override these values when debugging
 * in order to tweak the default logging behavior.
 */
#ifndef RCTLOG_REDBOX_LEVEL
#define RCTLOG_REDBOX_LEVEL RCTLogLevelError
#endif

/**
 * Logging macros. Use these to log information, warnings and errors in your
 * own code.
 */
#define RCTLog(...) _RCTLog(RCTLogLevelInfo, __VA_ARGS__)
#define RCTLogTrace(...) _RCTLog(RCTLogLevelTrace, __VA_ARGS__)
#define RCTLogInfo(...) _RCTLog(RCTLogLevelInfo, __VA_ARGS__)
#define RCTLogAdvice(string, ...) RCTLogWarn([@"(ADVICE) " stringByAppendingString:(NSString *)string], __VA_ARGS__)
#define RCTLogWarn(...) _RCTLog(RCTLogLevelWarning, __VA_ARGS__)
#define RCTLogError(...) _RCTLog(RCTLogLevelError, __VA_ARGS__)

/**
 * An enum representing the severity of the log message.
 */
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, RCTLogLevel) {
  RCTLogLevelTrace = 0,
  RCTLogLevelInfo = 1,
  RCTLogLevelWarning = 2,
  RCTLogLevelError = 3,
  RCTLogLevelFatal = 4
};

/**
 * An enum representing the source of a log message.
 */
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, RCTLogSource) {
  RCTLogSourceNative = 1,
  RCTLogSourceJavaScript = 2
};

/**
 * A block signature to be used for custom logging functions. In most cases you
 * will want to pass these arguments to the RCTFormatLog function in order to
 * generate a string.
 */
typedef void (^RCTLogFunction)(
  RCTLogLevel level,
  RCTLogSource source,
  NSString *fileName,
  NSNumber *lineNumber,
  NSString *message
);

/**
 * A method to generate a string from a collection of log data. To omit any
 * particular data from the log, just pass nil or zero for the argument.
 */
RCT_EXTERN NSString *RCTFormatLog(
  NSDate *timestamp,
  RCTLogLevel level,
  NSString *fileName,
  NSNumber *lineNumber,
  NSString *message
);

/**
 * A method to generate a string RCTLogLevel
 */
RCT_EXTERN NSString *RCTFormatLogLevel(RCTLogLevel);

/**
 * A method to generate a string from a RCTLogSource
 */
RCT_EXTERN NSString *RCTFormatLogSource(RCTLogSource);

/**
 * The default logging function used by RCTLogXX.
 */
extern RCTLogFunction RCTDefaultLogFunction;

/**
 * These methods get and set the global logging threshold. This is the level
 * below which logs will be ignored. Default is RCTLogLevelInfo for debug and
 * RCTLogLevelError for production.
 */
RCT_EXTERN void RCTSetLogThreshold(RCTLogLevel threshold);
RCT_EXTERN RCTLogLevel RCTGetLogThreshold(void);

/**
 * These methods get and set the global logging function called by the RCTLogXX
 * macros. You can use these to replace the standard behavior with custom log
 * functionality.
 */
RCT_EXTERN void RCTSetLogFunction(RCTLogFunction logFunction);
RCT_EXTERN RCTLogFunction RCTGetLogFunction(void);

/**
 * This appends additional code to the existing log function, without replacing
 * the existing functionality. Useful if you just want to forward logs to an
 * extra service without changing the default behavior.
 */
RCT_EXTERN void RCTAddLogFunction(RCTLogFunction logFunction);

/**
 * This method temporarily overrides the log function while performing the
 * specified block. This is useful for testing purposes (to detect if a given
 * function logs something) or to suppress or override logging temporarily.
 */
RCT_EXTERN void RCTPerformBlockWithLogFunction(void (^block)(void), RCTLogFunction logFunction);

/**
 * This method adds a conditional prefix to any messages logged within the scope
 * of the passed block. This is useful for adding additional context to log
 * messages. The block will be performed synchronously on the current thread.
 */
RCT_EXTERN void RCTPerformBlockWithLogPrefix(void (^block)(void), NSString *prefix);

/**
 * Private logging function - ignore this.
 */
#if RCTLOG_ENABLED
#define _RCTLog(lvl, ...) _RCTLogNativeInternal(lvl, __FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define _RCTLog(lvl, ...) do { } while (0)
#endif

RCT_EXTERN void _RCTLogNativeInternal(RCTLogLevel, const char *, int, NSString *, ...) NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(4,5);
RCT_EXTERN void _RCTLogJavaScriptInternal(RCTLogLevel, NSString *);
```

Comment: Is your React headers directory specified in in the Header Search Path for your Project?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your poodle

```
target 'myProjectTests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
  #Or if you have a collective pod list reference by a variable. For example if its 'shared_pod', just add shared_pods before end (which is the next line)
end
```